# Are large forms and document databases a good match?

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb, webforms

I have inherited the support of very large web form that is processed in PHP.  I'm seasoned at PHP development, but the original authors weren't.  Currently the data is persisted in a relational database, but I'm considering switching to a document database (mongodb in particular) and would be interested to know if this use case sounds like a good match for a document database.

==== the current situation ====

There are about 1400 form elements (yes, you read that correctly) spread over several tabs in the user interface.  The form element names map one-to-one to columns in the database.  For some reason, it is spanned across 4 database tables.  Possibly mysql had a limit to the number of columns.  I've refactored the data saving dramatically, but it is a pain to query the back end.

Part of the use case for this form is that a person fills it out each year.  When the form is "opened" the prior year data is copied forward.  In this way they don't have to re-enter things that remained the same.  For most people they only need a fraction of the form fields.  There are about 25 places where a person can upload a document in lieu of entering data directly.  This form doesn't get heavy traffic.

One of the ugliest things about it is how form space is allocated.  If you have 10 'foo' elements you have 10 columns in the databased called foo1, foo2, etc.  Need an 11th one?  Add a column to the db, edit the html and PHP.  Gag.  Oh yeah, make sure to do the same for the printable version too.

The current design makes no use of relations.  I don't have performance concerns, but it is cumbersome to manage and it just "feels wrong" to store/retrieve the data like this.

==== discarded solution ====

For a while I considered making a proper relational table so that I could have my 11th 'foo' form element without altering the db schema or form.  As I mapped it out the ER diagram became a bit overwhelming.  My gut said this was an improvement in architecture, but there must be a simpler solution.

==== proposed solution ====

So, I propose to write a script to port the data over to a mongodb store and start writing/reading from it instead.  It will still have a mammoth amount of fields, but the data management seems more sensible.  If I want an 11th 'foo' I just store it.  If there is a hierarchy of data, it is all in one place.

Are there pitfalls I should be aware of here?  Would people recommend other approaches?

Comment: You may want to approach this by first figuring out how you will need to process the data. Will it be searchable? If so, how? How will it be manipulated? Is this data shared by other systems? This may help you decide what format and database system you may want to use.

Comment: Good points, KTF.  I left some details out for brevity, but the search needs are quite limited for the data.  It wouldn't feed into other systems.  It is about as close to behaving like a paper form as you can get.  It isn't quite "store and forget" but it is close because after it is saved and read it is rarely referred back to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has nothing to do with RDBMS vs. NoSQL - every proper designed backend database layer can deal with such an issue. In the world of ORMs it is fairly easy being flexible with changing database requirements and complex database schematas. The same applies to NoSQL databases - although they usually have no schema. Anyway what is your point?

Comment: I think he's asking for input on his proposed solution, and to see if anyone has any input from experience on what may be the easiest to work with/maintain... however, this usually depends on many factors and is very specific to the system[s] he may be working with...

Comment: RestRisiko, in the abandoned approach I had started some work using symfony 1.3 and Doctrine as the ORM to rebuild it.  I have solid experience using various ORM tools (adodb, pdo, doctrine, propel) and it seemed like I was creating a new kind of complexity going the normalized relational route.  I know an RDBMS can work but because document databases are a little new to me I'm curious if my use case sounds reasonable.

Comment: I'm returning to this after a long while and with some more experience about the situation see that @Blaackmoon is right that this isn't relevant to the database mechanism.